# TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones wrong timezone (name)

Tags: c#, .net, timezone

Microsoft defined a [list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms912391(v=winembedded.11).aspx) of all timezones and their name.

E.g. 110    W. Europe Standard Time (GMT+01:00) Amsterdam, Berlin, Bern, Rome, Stockholm, Vienna

The name of the timezone is wrong, because it should be [**Central** European Time](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/netherlands/amsterdam) instead of **Western**.

Perphaps you know a solution to retrieve a correct list of timezones?

Comment: Are you sure as 095 is central...

Comment: You are making an assertion.

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

- The page you linked to is *only* valid for Windows Embedded 1.1 - an ancient and deprecated product.  That page is for historical reference only.  Microsoft does not maintain a web page with the list of time zones supported in modern Windows and .NET, because the values change often as the world's time zones are updated as a result of geopolitical changes.  Instead, use .NET's  `TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones()`, or `tzutil.exe /l` on the command line.
- The value you described is similar to the `DisplayName` property returned on a `TimeZoneInfo` object when the OS language is English.  These values are primarily for time zone selection - that is, picking a time zone from a drop down list of available time zones.  As such, Windows elects to provide city names for some of the time zones, rather than the broader colloquial names.
- To get a value like `"Central European Time"`, you would need to use data from the [Unicode CLDR project](http://cldr.unicode.org), or from a library that consumes that data.  The data is given in many different languages, so you will need to know both the identifier of the time zone, and the language/locale that you are interested in.
- One such library that gives CLDR data for time zones in .NET is [TimeZoneNames](https://github.com/mj1856/TimeZoneNames) - of which I am the author.  Using this library is straightforward.  Once installed from Nuget, just call `TZNames.GetNamesForTimeZone` and pass either a an IANA time zone identifier, or a Windows time zone identifier, along with an IETF language tag for the language/locale you are interested in.  The samples in the project readme explain further.

Comment: Just to mention - here is it bit fresher (05/02/2017) [Microsoft link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/default-time-zones). And on date of commenting same zone

    W. Europe Standard Time (GMT+01:00) Amsterdam, Berlin, Bern, Rome, Stockholm, Vienna

is shown on my Win 10 `tzutil.exe /l` output.
Nevertheless, thanks for pointing to the `TimeZoneNames`

Comment: Keep in mind that page lists the *default* time zones when installing Windows.  It doesn't list *all available* time zones.